# Windows 8 Goes To Sleep When It Shouldn't

Tags: windows-8, sleep

I have an installation of Windows 8 Pro that goes into sleep mode when I leave the computer unattended for a few minutes. This does not always happen, and there was a few weeks where it didn't sleep at all unless I forced it, but it is now happening again.

I have, many times, looked at the power settings both basic and advanced. I have tried many options for the period to wait before entering sleep mode, and currently have it set to Never for both screen and computer.

Still, the computer insists on going to sleep, yesterday within a minute of leaving the keyboard, when the settings say it shouldn't.

Unless I missed some setting somewhere. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does the device have a dedicated button for sleeping? Perhaps its stuck :)

Comment: I was using on the previous OS the front panel button to sleep the PC, but that isn't working now. It only turns the PC on. Something else to look at :)